# Why is else if producing different results compared to a switch?

Tags: c

I have a simple piece of code that detects keystrokes using `ncurses`.

As I understand, 1 keypress pushes 3 values into the buffer. Where the 3rd value differentiates between arrow keys for example.

So when pressing any of the 4 arrows on the keyboard, the first 2 values pushed into the buffer should be similar `\033`, and `[`. But the 3rd value is unique to the arrow (`A` for up, `B` for down, `C` for right or `D` for left). Therefore, when mapping actions to keystrokes, we're depending on the 3rd value.

When trying to assess which arrow was pressed I tried both an `if else` ladder and a `switch`. The `if else` ladder works perfectly. But the switch seems to fire multiple cases on each keypress.

Here's the working code (if else) -

```
char first = getch(); //returns \033
char second = getch(); //returns [
char third = getch(); // returns A or B or C or D

if(third == 'A'){
printf("Up Arrow Pressed");
}
else if(third == 'B'){
printf("Down Arrow Pressed");
}
else if(third == 'C'){
printf("Right Arrow Pressed");
}
else if(third == 'D'){
printf("Left Arrow Pressed");
}
```

Here's the code that isn't working (Case) -

```
char first = getch(); //returns \033
char second = getch(); //returns [
char third = getch(); // returns A or B or C or D


switch(third){
    case('B'):
        printf("\nDOWN");
    case('C'):
        printf("\nRIGHT");
    case('A'):
        printf("\nUP");
    case('D'):
        printf("\nLEFT");
    default:
        printf("default");
    }
```

This is the output when cases are used and I press the down key:

[image]

Comment: `if(third == "A")` needs to be `if(third == 'A')`. Same for the other conditionals.

Comment: You forgot the `break;` statement at the end of each case in the switch.

Comment: @kaylum: Also, if it's not just a typo, a couple of `Third`s need to be `third`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you don't `break;` at the end of a case the next case is executed.

Answer (score 0):

If You Don't Use `break` at the end of each case then the cases that you write after the true case will also be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Use "break; " (same as in the code provided as image) as last statement in each case so that it prevents execution of followed cases.!
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/up2pG.png)

Comment: Please post your code directly to the question, no need of adding extra URLs that can become invalid in future.